# Prevent dynamic asset to make multiple http requests when it's toggled in Nuxt 3

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I created a component for a Dynamic image Carousel in **Nuxt 3** that at its core uses the following template:

```
      <Transition name="fade">
        <img
          v-if="showFirstImage && images.firstImage"
          draggable="false"
          loading="lazy"
          class="absolute object-contain w-full h-full"
          :alt="carouselDescription"
          :src="images.firstImage"
        >
      </Transition>
```

I pass as a prop an array of images that are stored in the `/public` folder, and after some time I show another image. The problem is that after each animation step where the `v-if` toggles itself to true again I see that the network shows a new request for an image that was already loaded (the carousel is cyclical, hence it will show the same image after some time).

Is there a way to cache the call or prevent any new network calls for the images that were already loaded Carousel strategy?

Comment: Since you're using `v-if`, you're removing it from the DOM. Hence why it is calling it again on the next iteration. You could probably rather use `v-show` here instead. And probably `loading="lazy"` could be helpful too.

Comment: @kissu using `v-show` also triggers new calls

Comment: What happens in the DOM? Your carousel is maybe removing them itself? Check your Vue devtools too, to see some of it's props (maybe something disabling that feature). Because as far as I know, images are supposed to be cached by default. Otherwise, it may come from somewhere else.

Comment: It seems that this is the usual behavior of the browser and not a Nuxt-related problem, whenever you dynamically change the `src` of an image the image is requested again. Now I wonder how I should cache the images

Comment: Why would you change the src of an image rather than having several images and using CSS for display purposes?

Comment: My purpose was to diminish the amount of DOM elements required for the animation

Comment: You can't do magic and keeping both DOM + network requests to a minimum. Prefer using DOM elements for that purpose. Especially since your markup probably already have a ton of unnecessary `div` already. Also, your carousel will have 30 elements at max? Should be totally fine.

Comment: Yes definitively right, I'll change my Carousel logic according to that, some lessons learned here. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

OP was using some reactive URL for his images' source, hence totally not cacheable.
Rather that toggling this in the DOM, the better and simpler approach is to either use `v-show` or handle the rest with CSS. A few more DOM nodes will not make or break anything performance-wise.
And it's probably better to have a few more nodes than to make more network requests.